# springmvc converter doesnot work

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, enums

I need convert string to enum. I wish I could post a `String` parameter ,and receive as an enum, but I got a 415 error.Here is my code

Email.java

```
public class Email {
    private String address;
    private String subject;
    private String content;
    private ServiceType service;

    public enum ServiceType {
        Feedback, PrivatePolicy, TermsOfUse, MotionDetection;
        public static ServiceType get(String type) {
            for (ServiceType servicetype : values()) {
                if (servicetype.toString().equals(type)) {
                    return servicetype;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`StringToEnumConverter` uesed to convert string to enum

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class StringToEnumConverter implements ConverterFactory<String, Enum> {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public <T extends Enum> Converter<String, T> getConverter(Class<T> targetType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new StringToEnum(targetType);
    }

    private class StringToEnum<T extends Enum> implements Converter<String, T> {  

        private final Class<T> enumType;  

        public StringToEnum(Class<T> enumType) {  
            this.enumType = enumType;  
        }  

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T convert(String source) {  
            if (source.length() == 0) {  
                return null;  
            }  
            return (T) Enum.valueOf(this.enumType, source.trim());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

xml inject the converter

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />
    <bean id="conversionService"class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.xxx.xxx.utils.StringToEnumConverter" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

front-end code

```js
$(".test").click(function(){
            $(".response-text").html("please wait....");
            var postData = {
               "address" : $(".email").val(),
               "subject" : $(".subject").val(),
               "content" : $(".content").val(),
               "service" : $(".service").val()
            }
            var args = {
                url: "XXX/emailService_v1.0",
                contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                type: "post",
                data: postData,
                success : function(response, currentAjaxOptions){
                    var str = JSON.stringify(response);
                    $(".response-text").html(str);
                }
            }
            $.xAjax(args);
        });
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/emailService_v1.0", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JSONObject emailService(@Valid @RequestBody Email email,
        BindingResult result) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("come in....");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return genResJsonFromError(result);
    } else {
        System.out.println(email.getAddress());
        JSONObject resJson = emailService.sendEmail(email);
        System.out.println(email.getService().toString());
        return resJson;
    }
}
```

I just found the StringToEnumConverter.java wan't invoked.
so it give me 415 Unsupported Media Type error.
Wish anyone can help me

Then I add

```
@Resource(name = "conversionService")
private ConversionService conversionService;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(DataBinder binder) {
    binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
}
```

in my controller, but it does not work either.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't be invoked. converters are only invoked for request parameters when doing binding. You are submitting a JSON body . Jackson is doing the marshalling/unmarshalling and you should tap into that.

Comment: THK for the answer, but I dont make it clear when you said "doing binding",does that mean I should add "binder.setConversionService(conversionService);" in initBinder method in my controller? I hava modify it , but it still does not work. Could you please give me more guide cause I am really a newer in spring..

Comment: No you are using conversion using `HttpMessageConverter`s binding is when request parameters (the things you don't use) are bound to properties on an object. You basically use serialization to/from JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much! yes when I use RequestBody annotation ,it means the parameter must be JSON, but I set the contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" , not "application/json", and after I move @RequestBody , everything goes OK ^_^.